# More efficient approach of creating class instances of different classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, initialization

Let's say we have a function `classes_init`. It takes in lists or other types of information which it uses to initialize many instances of different types of classes, such as:

```
["spam", 24]
["eggs", 10]
["bacon", 20]
...
```

Index 0 of those lists indicates what type of class it is supposed to be. The best way I found of initializing instances of specific classes is through something like the following:

```
def classes_init(xlists):
    classlist = list()
    if xlists[0] == "spam":
        classlist.append(Spam(number=xlists[1]))
    elif xlists[0] == "eggs":
        classlist.append(Eggs(number=xlists[1]))
    elif xlists[0] == "bacon":
        classlist.append(Bacon(number=xlists[1]))
    ... and so on ...
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this? This is a lot of repetition, so it almost assuredly means this is a wrong approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a dictionary to map string to class:

```
class_map = {
    'spam': Spam,
    'eggs': Eggs,
    'bacon': Bacon,
}

def classes_init(xlists):
    classlist = [class_map[name](argument) for name, argument in xlists]
```

The class map could be created from the class names, if all the strings correspond to the lowercased name:

```
classes = (Spam, Eggs, Bacon)
class_map = {cls.__name__.lower(): cls for cls in classes}
```

Comment: Would be cool if you could add the code how to instantiate the class n times as OP asked.

Comment: The dicts are a very good answer, but I am not very familiar with list comprehensions. What exactly is happening there? I am testing around with code as you have illustrated, and I keep getting `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)` and so on.

Comment: @Holsterbau: a list comprehension is just an optimised `list.append()` loop. So for each iteration, the result of `class_map[name](argument)` is appended, and the iterations come from `for name, argument in xlists`. Your error is on the `for` loop side, which requires all elements in `xlists` to be a sequence of two values (so your lists in your question, or tuples, or something else that can produce 2 values), the error indicates that at least one element in the `xlists` list has only a single element.

Comment: @Holsterbau: see [Python for-in loop preceded by a variable](//stackoverflow.com/q/6475314) for a more comprehensive list comprehensions explanation.

Answer (score -2):

Remove the `if-elif` structure and add this to yor code:

```
exec("classList.append(" + xlists[0].title() + "(number = xlists[1])")
```

This way, less memory and less time is required than manually entering your data into a `dict`, but it can be more dangerous if `xlists` contains strings formatted as code, so make sure you clean the strings before running this code.

Comment: I doub't `exec` is faster than using a `dict`